# replace all dots contained within braces

Tags: sed

In a file, a would like to replace all occurences of a dot within braces to be replaced by an underscore.

input

```
something.dots {test.test} foo.bar
another.line
```

expected output

```
something.dots {test_test} foo.bar
another.line
```

What would be the easiest way to achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose the least ugly sed from the two options below:

```
$ cat file
something.dots {test.test} foo.bar {a.a} x
something.dots
$ sed 's|\({[^}]*\)\.\([^}]*}\)|\1_\2|g' file
something.dots {test_test} foo.bar {a_a} x
something.dots
$ sed -E 's|(\{[^}]*)\.([^}]*\})|\1_\2|g' file
something.dots {test_test} foo.bar {a_a} x
something.dots
```

Explanation (I'll use the last form, but they are equivalent):

- `(\{[^}]*)`: Matching group 1 consisting of a `{`, and any number of non-`}` characters.
- `\.`: A dot.
- `([^}]*\})`: Matching group 2 consisting of any number of non-`}` characters followed by a `}`.

If found, replace the whole expression by `[Matching group 1].[Matching group 2]`.

Answer (score 1):

> easiest way

Hold the line, extract the part within braces, do the substitution, grab the holded line and shuffle it for the output.

```
sed 'h;s/.*{//;s/}.*//;s/\./_/g;G;s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*{\).*}/\2\1}/'
```

@edit - ignore lines without `{.*}`:

```
sed '/{.*}/!b; h;s/.*{//;s/}.*//;s/\./_/g;G;s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*{\).*}/\2\1}/'
```

[Tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/MidnightblueWastefulAbandonware#main.sh).

Comment: its not working for a line containing no braces (I edited my question to add it to the example)

Comment: So? So add a condition so that it doesn't run for a line that contains no braces? [here is a great sed introduction](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Comment: Sure, there's a typo. fixed

Answer (score 0):

**If it's going to be the "easiest way"** use AWK instead of sed and then:

```
awk -F"{|}" '$0 !~ /{.*}/{print($0)}; gsub("\.","_",$2) {print($1"{"$2"}"$3)}' file
```

This will replace any number of dots, e.g. {test.test.test} and lines without parentheses leaves unchanged.

Explanation:

```
-F"{|}"                    Sets the field separator to { or }
$0 !~ /{.*}/{print($0)};   Prints lines unchanged without the {. *} 
                           pattern, "print" can be omitted as this is 
                           the default behavior
gsub("\.","_",$2)          Substitutions . to _ for field 2
{print($1"{"$2"}"$3)}      Formats and prints lines after changes
```

Comment: @KamilCuk You're right. You can write it 'cleverly' a little simplified. However, people who don't know the nuances of AWK read it later, so I prefer to write a little longer but more clearly.